# How to dismiss a Snackbar when user interact elsewhere?

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar, snackbar

How to dismiss a Snackbar when user interact elsewhere, like the way Gmail app dismiss Snackbars when user scrolls, clicks elsewhere, leaves the activity etc.

This behavior has also been mentioned in [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe override `dispatchTouchEvent` in Activity.

```
private Snackbar mSnackbar;

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (mSnackbar != null && mSnackbar.isShown()) {

                Rect sRect = new Rect();
                mSnackbar.getView().getHitRect(sRect);

                //This way the snackbar will only be dismissed if
                //the user clicks outside it.
                if (!sRect.contains((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY())) {
                    mSnackbar.dismiss();
                    mSnackbar == null;
                }
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Thanks to Eme's and gicci's comments for improvement to this. (I haven't tested this new slightly edited verstion).

Comment: You don't need update 'mSnackbarShown', you can use the isShown method of the SnackBar, in this way you don't need set the callback, only with the dispatchTouchEvent is valid.

Comment: You shall use getGlobalVisibleRect() instead of getHitRect(). Thee is also a typo on "mSnackBar == null".

Comment: fixed typo thanks. why is getGlobalVisibleRect better? I actually copied the getHitRect() bit from somewhere else so don't really know what's better.

Answer (score 1):

As the guidelines that you provided in your question state:

> or user interaction elsewhere **(such as summoning a new surface or activity)**

It does not mention anything regarding swipes or clicks while the snackbar is displayed.

In other words, so long as the user remains on the same activity the snackbar should just disappear on it's own after a timeout or if the user delibaretly swipes it off.

Also, I checked Google's Gmail app and the snackbars don't disappear if the user swipes on the same screen.

Comment: It clearly says "such as...", not only summoning a new activity, but also clicking, scrolling, leaving etc. are user interactions and Gmail app dismiss snackbars immediately (before its timeout) if you scroll or click any where on the screen.